# Query params are ignored from publisher.url in SiddhiQL

Tags: siddhi

The query params placed in publisher.url are not been sent to the server.
Here is the code snippet

```
  @App:name("Http_trial")
@App:description("Description of the plan")

define stream SweetProductionStream (projectCode string, totalBid int );     


@sink(type="http",
        method="POST",
        headers="'Content-Type:application/json','Accept:application/json','Host:192.168.43.79'",
        follow.redirect='true',
        publisher.url = "http://192.168.43.79:8080/path?abc=xyz",
        @map(type='json', validate.json='true', @payload("""{"properties":[{"name":"amount","value":"100"}]}""")))
define stream LowProductionAlertStream (projectCode string, totalBid int);


@info(name = 'query1')
from SweetProductionStream 
select *
insert into LowProductionAlertStream;
```

Packet captured using Wireshark
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T32cF.jpg)

The request uri seen in the packet details only contains /path and is missing ?abc=xyz
Is there any other way to specify query params ? Or am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in the latest version of the extension, [v1.0.36](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/wso2/extension/siddhi/io/http/siddhi-io-http/1.0.36/siddhi-io-http-1.0.36.jar) onwards